# How and where should I put a version number in my Django project?

Tags: django, version, django-settings

I'm making a Django project consisting of several apps and I want to use a version number for the whole project, which would be useful for tracking the status of the project between each time it comes to production.

I've read and googled and I've found how to put a version number for each django app of mine, but not for a whole project.

I assume that the **settings.py** (in my case it would be base.py, because the settings are inherited for each environment: developmente, pre-production, production) would be the ideal file for storing it, but I would like to know good practices from other Django programmers, because I haven't found any.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've ever needed to do this, but the two obvious choices would be either the settings file, as you state, or alternatively the `__init__.py` in the main project app.

Comment: I'm studying it along with the other answer and decide which one is best

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it to relate to django, you can tag a commit in your source control to provide a marker of a particular version (as well as a separate branch for releases).

From the [docs for git tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

> Git has the ability to tag specific points in history as being important. Typically people use this functionality to mark release points (v1.0, and so on).

You could use the same versioning number system as google if you so wish which relates to

```
year.month.day.optional_revision  # i.e 2016.05.03 for today
```

Doing this would make it easier to track back to previous versions since it won't be overwritten in source code by newer version numbers.

Comment: For only the version control Git is enough, but I want also to display the version in my app.
I will look at your link, though, because it is interesting.

Comment: @madtyn - For that, we have created a separate product_version.py file in the base app and then import a function from this where needed

Comment: A function? It is not a constant?

I could use a source code example

Comment: @madtyn - I can't really include source code I'm afraid but its just a function that returns a string made up of separate components that we use (think major revision, minor revision etc)

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand you, ok. I got it now.